# UserControl window won't close

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a problem with one of my UserControl Windows.
I have a MainWindow and when a specific situatuin appears, another UserControl will open.
It has two Buttons which sends a command and after that it should be closed.
Right now it only opens the Window and sends the command, but doesn't close it afterwards.
I hope you can help me.
Code:
xaml:

C#:
Code to open the UserControl:

```
Window window = new Window();
window.Content = new MsgBox();
window.ShowDialog();
```

Button declaration:
    public DelegateCommand OkBtn { get; set; }

Buttonfunction added to button:

```
OkBtn = new DelegateCommand<object>(OkBtnFkt);
```

In this Buttonfunction there should be something like: window.Close();

What I have tried:

Window.Close();
Sends the Window.close through the dispatcher to the UI

Comment: Any code you can show?

Comment: You are still not showing enough codes for us to fully understand what is going on. For example, how does your `MsgBox` (presumed to be an UserControl) close its parent (Window)? And if you want a messagebox with custom look, why don't you sub-class Window instead of UserControl?

Comment: I am sorry for the missing parts. The parent UserControl isn't closed. It is still in the background but waits for an action inside the new UserControl.
I have to use a UserControl because of the company

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer.
This post had the answer for me :
http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/91746/Close-WPF-user-control-inside-WPF-form-application

Comment: So in the end it's the problem of not being able to get a reference of the parent window from usercontrol?

Comment: Yeah, sort of. The Application thought, it was still inside the mainwindow so the close call couldn't be executed. I had to select the newly created window due to the commandparameter of the Button.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the DialogResult of the window. What you actually have is a window with a UserControl inside. You could make a MsgBoxWindow to derive from Window. Place your control and a Close Button inside. Then if close button is clicked you can set the DialogResult.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.dialogresult(v=vs.110).aspx

Anyway why don't you use MessageBox?

Comment: My "Window" is a UserControl and I have to close it. I also added some Code in this question

Comment: I need a designed Messagebox. It should be used for different things. But true, I simply want a designed MessageBox